# Set maximum input number

Tags: php

My question is quite complex. I am currently working on a loan system. I have two tables regarding loan module:

- item
- loan

When the item is being loaned, the loaned quantity will be subtracted from the inventory(item_qty - loan_qty). My problem comes at the update loan module. I don't know how to set the maximum quantity. I know that I just need to add the item_qty and loan_qty, but I can't find the way to do so.

I've googled for a long time and still stuck. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $loan_id=$_GET['loan_id'];
    $acc_query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `loan` natural join `item` WHERE loan_id = '$_REQUEST[loan_id]'  ") or die(mysqli_error());
    $acc_fetch = $acc_query->fetch_array();
?>

<div>
<form method="post" action="update_loan.php" >
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="loan_id" value="<?php echo $loan_id; ?>">  

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label>Quantity</label>
        <input name="n_qty" type = "number" id = "n_qty" value= "<?php echo $acc_fetch['qty']?>" class = "form-control" min="1" max="??" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Table inventory:

- item_id
- item_code
- item_name
- item_qty

Table loan:

- loan_id
- item_id
- loan_qty
- loaned_place

Comment: Please add more explanation or code, what is meany by *how to set the maximum quantity. * You have inventory table, and getting load is subtracted from that table, ok then what is the exactly the problem.

Comment: Share the database table schema and and some seed data for those tables to replicate your problem.

Comment: I've edited my question. @M_Idrees , my problem is, when updating the loan, i need to set the maximum number for the quantity input, where i need to sum up the item_qty from the inventory table and loan_qty from the loan table. I don't know how to do so

Comment: Do you need to cross check the Total number of qnt in Loan Table should be less than or equal to the Total number of qnt in the Inventory Table ???

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan , nope. I've done that. It's the update module. For example, the user input the wrong quantity for the loan and he need to edit it. my problem comes at setting the maximum number of the quantity because i need to add the loan_qty and item_qty which are from the different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply use group by `item_id, item_code, item_name` and then use `sum()` function to get sum of qty from both tables: `inventory` and `loan`, and subtract to get the desired one.

```
SELECT i.item_id,i.item_code,i.item_name, (SUM(i.item_qty) - SUM(l.loan_qty)) AS ResultQty
FROM `inventory` i
natural join `loan` l
GROUP BY i.item_id,i.item_code,i.item_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping me guys. I've got some idea instead. Here is my solution:

```
<?php
$loan_id=$_GET['loan_id'];
$acc_query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `loan` natural join `item` WHERE loan_id = '$_REQUEST[loan_id]'  ") or die(mysqli_error());
$acc_fetch = $acc_query->fetch_array();

$qty1 = $acc_fetch['loan_qty']; // declaring the Loan quantity as $qty1
$item_id = $acc_fetch["item_id"]; // get the item_id from the loan table

$sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE item_id = '$item_id'  ") or die(mysqli_error());
$row = $sql->fetch_array();

$qty2 = $row['item_qty']; // declaring the item quantity from as $qty2

$qtyy = $qty1 + $qty2; // sum up the quantity 

    <div>
    <form method="post" action="update_loan.php" >
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="loan_id" value="<?php echo $loan_id; ?>">  

    <div class = "form-group">
    <label>Quantity</label>
    <input name="n_qty" type = "number" id = "n_qty" value= "<?php echo 
    $acc_fetch['qty']?>" class = "form-control" min="1" max="<?php echo "$qtyy"; ?>" /> // set the maximum number input  
    </div>
    </div>
   ?>
```